# Are Azure WebRole and Owin configuration start in isolated threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, azure-web-roles, owin

I have some static type that I'm initializing in OnStart method of WebRole entry point.
As I know, web role is executed before any other initializer. I assumed that initialized static data in Web Role entry point will be accessible from any child threads, but when I'm trying to read my static data in one of the OWIN configuration files (SignalR in my case) - it's empty like it's never been initialized.

Why I cannot access this data from OWIN thread? 
Are web role and owin middlewares ran in it's own isolated thread?

Hope someone can explain me this part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebRole entry point runs in WaIISHost.exe and OWIN runs in w3wp.exe.  You will need to do your type initialization in your OWIN startup.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2011/05/05/windows-azure-role-architecture.aspx is a handy reference to see where different things run in an Azure VM.